adb reverse tcp:8080: lost suddenly during USB android debugging
adb reverse: lost suddenly during android USB debugging.
 > adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080
 UsbFfs tcp:8080 tcp:8080

During VSC debugging, sometimes it gets lost suddenly.
  > adb reverse --list

empty. What can be the cause?
Sometimes it lost connection even when adb reverse is active:
Debugging console:
D/SurfaceView@876b756(10017): updateSurface: surface is not valid
I/SurfaceView@876b756(10017): releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@a5326f4[MainActivity]
D/SurfaceView@876b756(10017): updateSurface: surface is not valid
I/SurfaceView@876b756(10017): releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@a5326f4[MainActivity]
Lost connection to device.

Exited.

Today It happens after about 5 minute debugging every time either due to adb reverse or simply lost connection.
UPDATE
Connection lost when using camera to take photo using image-picker plugin.

The connection can be interrupted if adb server that is running on your PC is restarted or vlosed. I would check the process ID of adb server instance and see if it changes when an interruption occurs.

I will check that next time it happens. Thanks
